# To check whether $\alpha$- limit point of a continuous map is a non-wandering point

Tags: dynamical-systems

Let $f:X\to X$ be a continuous map and $x\in X$.
A point $y\in X$ is called an $\alpha$-limit point of $x$ under $f$ if and
only if there is a strictly increasing sequence of positive integer $\{k_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ and a sequence of points $\{y_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ such that

1) $f^{k_n}(y_n)= x$

2) $\lim_{n\to \infty} y_n= y$.

Also, a point $y\in X$ is called a non-wandering point, if for every open set $U$ of $y$, there is $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f^n(U)\cap U\neq \emptyset$.

I know that if $f$ is a homeomorphism, then every $\alpha$- limit point of $x$ is a non-wandering point. But I do not know if $f$ is a continuous map, then every $\alpha$- limit point of $x$ is a non-wandering point?

Please help me to know it.

Comment: I've never encountered this way of defining $\alpha$-limit point (maybe it's specific for case when $f$ is not invertible), but shouldn't $k_n$ be decreasing? What part of definition corresponds to "time going backwards"?

Comment: @Evgeny, $f^{k_n}(y_n)=x$ means that $y_n$ is in backwards orbit of $x$, but $f$ is not invertible .

Comment: Thank you very much, now I think I got this definition!

Comment: The answer to your question is yes. Hint: Notice that after taking $m>n$ with $f^{k_n}(y_n)=f^{k_m}(y_m)$ you can assume without loss of generality that $y_n$ is such that $f^{m-n}(y_m)=y_n$.